# The multi-part identifier "dbo.function_namee" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_namee
(
) 
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @var datetime 
    SELECT @var=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    RETURN @var 
END
```

And:

```
select dbo.function_namee
```

When i try to execute `select dbo.function_namee` it gives an error. can you guys help me?

Comment: Try `select dbo.function_namee()`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the brackets from the end of the function which makes SQL Server try to locate an object called `function_namee` instead of finding the function. For example:

```
select dbo.function_namee()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
select dbo.function_namee()
```

Comment: You are Welcome, Please Mark the Question as Answered if your Query is Solved